# Java. How to make a bot

Tags: java, helper, bots

I wonder is possible to make a bot writen in JAVA, which will open some program(program is under windows), click on the button in this program and type some data, check status of this program(login or logout, this is client for online game). 
Which JAVA tools I need ? I think that java robot lib is not enough for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is it not enough for what you need? Show your code and ask a specific programming question that is answerable.

Comment: Question was just a theory, I never before seen Robot libs in use, I just want to know some opinion before I start develop something. Thanks for Your time.

Comment: Try AutoIt. It's designed for this.

Answer (score -8):

You cannot do this using JAVA.
JAVA is a language which is loosely coupled with operating systems, so it can only receive mouse/key messages from underlying OS. Among all the tasks you mentioned , it can only start the program by using Runtime.execute.

If you want to implement a software like this ,you should use Visual Studio and use Microsoft technologies.

Comment: The Java `Robot` class can move the mouse and send keystrokes right out of the box; I'm not sure why you'd say it isn't possible.

Comment: This question refers to this behaviour; [How to simulate a real mouse click using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185162/how-to-simulate-a-real-mouse-click-using-java). Obviously its really horrible to figure out where you should be clicking, but it can be done