# How to run exe file in Java program

Tags: java, exe

How can a `exe` file be executed in Java code in NetBeans?
I write a code to run a exe file in Java,

```
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd.exe /C start C:/Users/123/Desktop/nlp.exe" );
```

This code runs the file.

This file have some section that I can click it and run different part of it.
Is it possible that I can use a code to access to that sections and run them in Java instead of clicking it?

edited code :

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd.exe /C start C:/Users/123/Desktop/nlp.exe" ); 

Robot bot = new Robot();
bot.mouseMove(100, 100);    
bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

Comment: I don't quite get your question but if `nlp.exe` is the application where you have to do a click selection then please check whether the application supports command line parameters.

Comment: no, It doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a click signal to the system and specify its position on the screen. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185162/how-to-simulate-a-real-mouse-click-using-java)

Comment: here the difficult part is to find the correct place to click

Comment: You have to compute it on your own. I don't think you can get any information about the content of the GUI.

Comment: thanks.I edited question and add code for using click.

Comment: it takes time to program run, so first robot click and then program run. what should I do to first run program and after that robot click?

Comment: You have to run the program first and wait for the UI to load (Thread.sleep or something)

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.awt.Robot` to generate a system mouse click for an external program.

- [How to simulate a real mouse click using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185162/how-to-simulate-a-real-mouse-click-using-java)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

There is no built-in way with Java to get an external window's coordinates, but it can be done using JNA. See this answer:

- [How to get the x and y of a program window in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091531/how-to-get-the-x-and-y-of-a-program-window-in-java)

**Edit**

Your comments and editing are changing the question, which is making answering here almost pointless. Per your last edit to the question though, if I understand correctly, you are now asking if possible to somehow trigger an event in the external application with Java, without triggering the mouse click.  In this case I think the answer is highly specific to the individual program.

If the event can be triggered via keypresses, then that might an another non-mouse option using `java.awt.Robot`.

*If* the program generates/responds to a Windows Message (at the windows api level), you could possibly send the same message via JNA and the windows api `SendMessage`. However, that can get complicated and requires that you are familiar with windows API and techniques for finding and working with those messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain commands like this

In this example I use "c:" then "dir" then "ipconfig". "cho end"

To keep the terminal open at the end :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"c: && dir && ipconfig\"");
```

To automatically close it at the end :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /c \"c: && dir && ipconfig\"");
```

**EDIT**

in your case that would be :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"C:/Users/123/Desktop/nlp.exe && whatever_other_commands_you_want\"");
```

Comment: did you mean? " ( "cmd.exe /C start /K \"C:/Users/123/Desktop/nlp.exe ipconfig\"" )"

Comment: excuse me, why should i add other command in "whatever_other_commands_you_want"?

Comment: because I thought you would like to perform other operations than just the first command