# Click and drag option (JAVA)

Tags: java, click, mouseclick-event

I'm looking for a possibility to to this basically:
User clicks, holds, moves to left and releases.
EDIT: I mean not by an user, but automated.
Any methods which offer this?

Comment: Java SE for desktop ?

Comment: could you describe what exactly you don't know what to do, what have you tried?

Comment: I know how to make a click with the robot class, but it has to drag it accross the screen before releasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automate mouse clicks, holds and moves you can look into the [Robot Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

This is the basics of a mouse click: where `x` and `y` is the coordinate of the point on the screen in pixels where you want to click.

```
public static void click(int x, int y) throws AWTException{
    Robot bot = new Robot();
    bot.mouseMove(x, y);    
    bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

Other mouse functionality can be acheived through [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Really depends on what you specfically want to acheive

See:

[How to perform mouseover function in Selenium WebDriver using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

[How to simulate a real mouse click using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185162/how-to-simulate-a-real-mouse-click-using-java)

If you record the coordinates accurately enough, and loop the amount of times you want to do the processes; you can pretty much automate most mouse clicks/drags.