# I have a xxx.exe file. When executed pops up a gui screen. I need to access "Start" button on that screen. How to do this through java code?

Tags: java

I need to execute xxx.exe from java code which will open a gui window. In that window I need to access "Start" button and click on it. All this must happen through java code. Can any one help me do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the "Window"/Program doesn't provide any API for the UI, you can only access it through the pixels and do a click with the mouse on the screen. You can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185162/how-to-simulate-a-real-mouse-click-using-java

Comment: Java doesn't sound to be the right tool for this kind of thing. Java is (mostly) platform independent, but what you do is very much platform dependant, so it'd make sense to do it with something that integrates with your platform more smoothly (like .net). Alternatively you could create some heavy JNI methods to help with what you're trying to do.