# Accessing Google sheets Service Account

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am new for accessing Google sheets with Java and get "Quick Start" work (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java), but it needs manual permission for the first run. Is there any sample java codes to get it work with Service Account? thanks

Answer (score -1):

If the position of authorization window is always the same, you can use Java robot.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;

public static void click(int x, int y) throws AWTException{
    Robot bot = new Robot();
    bot.mouseMove(x, y);    
    bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

[1] [How to simulate a real mouse click using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185162/how-to-simulate-a-real-mouse-click-using-java)
[2] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv3QO14DJOQ