# how do you send mouseMove events to a java application?

Tags: java

Given a java application that handles mouse events, how does one write a separate java application that sends/ or intercepts the mouse handler on it to send input to it without actually having to manually  use the real mouse?

Comment: Are you asking how to emulate a mouse? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185162/how-to-simulate-a-real-mouse-click-using-java

Comment: thank you i tried to google it but i was seeing mixed results

Comment: You may need to enable OS accessibility functionality for your executable when using Robot. For example on Mac, under Security & Privacy > Privacy tab > Accessibility