# Simulate page click with coordinates (x,y)

Tags: java, htmlunit

How do I simulate a click with coordinates on `HtmlPage` then get the result a `HtmlPage`?

I want to click a button without an id or a name

I'm using the library **com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit**

Answer (score 0):

not sure about specific system or browser settings, but in general you can do this by following:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Robot;
public class test {
int xparam=50;
int yparam=100;
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  Robot mybot = null;
  try {
   mybot = new Robot();
  } catch (Exception failed) {
   System.err.println("Failed instant. Robot: " + failed);
  }
  int maske = InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK;

  mybot.mouseMove(xparam,yparam);
  mybot.mousePress(maske);
  mybot.mouseRelease(maske);
 }
}
```

For a smoother solution take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387483/how-to-move-a-mouse-smoothly-throughout-the-screen-by-using-java) ;

Comment: This is not the answer I'm looking for, I'm using gui-less html (HtmlUnit library)

Answer (score 0):

No,You can't click button with coordinates(X,Y).
Please specify the element other attributes because it can be click with help of other attribute